# Issue with siteSpeedSampleRate with metrics and dimensions

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm tracking search filed on an application like so:

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-y', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100, 'sampleRate': 100, 'cookieDomain': 'none'}); 
ga('set', {"metric8": 4321, "metric9": 1, "dimension3": "0000020131028143820", "metric7": 20131023, "metric1": 1, "metric6": 20131020, "dimension1": "00193", "metric10": 2}); 
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

This will create duplicate since it'll launch 2 request to Analytics:

- One with a pageview, metrics, dimansion
- One with the timing (caused by "siteSpeedSampleRate") with again the metrics and dimension.

Now, if I use this line instead :

```
ga('send', 'timing');
```

it'll stop the duplicate BUT the column "Avg. Page Load Time (sec)" will always equal 0.

Does anyone have a solution to this?
Thanks, have a good day!

Comment: I found a hack around... I need to wait 8 hours before posting. I'll come back and post my solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution but still not happy with it...

```
ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-y', {'siteSpeedSampleRate': 100, 'sampleRate': 100, 'cookieDomain': 'none'}); 
ga('send', 'pageview'); 
ga('set', {"metric8": 4321, "metric9": 1, "dimension3": "0000020131028143820", "metric7": 20131023, "metric1": 1, "metric6": 20131020, "dimension1": "00193", "metric10": 2});
```

what I understand is that by the time the "pageview" is sent async, I associate the metrics and dimensions so the "siteSpeedSampleRate" get it and send it to Analytics. 
(they are both sent a few milliseconds appart)

I can confirm this logs properly inside Analytics using custom reports but it looks wrong in so many ways...